# Notes 8.5.3 Remote system no longer responding on mail.box

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a remote user going through a VPN that cannot sent attachments bigger than about 1000kb. They get the following error.

"Remote system no longer responding on (our server) mail.box"

Any ideas on what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that their connection sucks and it's timing out or dropping while sending. I used to see issues like that a lot with people using slow internet connections, esp. if they were using satellite or something with limited bandwidth.